# Enable submit button after all validation

Tags: jquery

I have a form and I am using focusin and focusout events and validating on focusout. And I disabled submit button at first and I want to enable it again after validation. Here is my code.

```
    $("document").ready(function() {
    $("#contact_submit").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("#first_name").focusin(function() {
        $("#Frist_name_comment").html('Please inter your first name.');
    }).focusout(function() {
        var first_name = $("#first_name").val();
        if(first_name == "") {
            $("#Frist_name_comment").html("First Name is required.");
        }else {
            $("#Frist_name_comment").html('OK');
        }
    });

    $("#last_name").focusin(function() {
        $("#Last_name_comment").html('Please inter your last name.');
    }).focusout(function() {
            var last_name = $("#last_name").val();
        if(last_name == "") {

            $("#Last_name_comment").html("Last Name is required.");
        }else {
            $("#Last_name_comment").html('OK');
        }
    });

    $("#email").focusin(function() {
        $("#Email_comment").html('Please inter a email address.');
    }).focusout(function() {
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var atpos = email.indexOf("@");
        var dotpos = email.lastIndexOf(".");
        if((email == "" || atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos+2 || dotpos+2 > email.length)) {
            mess == "Not a vallied email.";
            $("#Email_comment").html("Not a valied email.");
        }else {
            $("#Email_comment").html('OK');
        }
    });

    // hear i want to enable submit button after all validation


});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("button").prop("disabled", true); <== for disabling
```

or

```
$("button").prop("disabled", false); <== for enabling
```

`disabled` attribute can also be BOOLEAN for indicating the state. jQuery has `.attr()` and

`.prop()` functions to access element's attributes. I have used `.prop()` , you can also use

`.attr()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
if($("#Last_name_comment).text()=='OK'|| 
   $('#Frist_name_comment).text()=='OK' || 
   $('#Last_name_comment').text()=='OK' || 
   $('#Email_comment").text()=='OK'){
  $("#contact_submit").removeAttr("disabled");
}
```

You have to check out the `OK` string if its there then remove the attr `disabled`

Comment: thanks bro for ur answer i think u understand my problem but that didn't work i tried that :)